# How do you dynamically resize two text label widths inside of a UITableViewCell?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiview

I'm using a table view that uses a custom UITableViewCell subclass, `NoteCell`. The subclass has two text labels, a name label and a date label which are side-by-side in the cell.  My goal is to have the name label resize itself so that the full date is shown no matter what.

in cellForRowAtIndexPath, I try to calculate and set the widths of the two text views so that the date is fully displayed and the name label is truncated.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"NoteCell";

    NoteCell *cell = (NoteCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.dateLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;

    cell.nameLabel.text = @"A name that should be truncated";
    cell.dateLabel.text = @"A long date to use as an example";

    // Set the widths
    // First calculate how wide the date label needs to be.
    cell.dateLabel.text = @"A really long date";
    CGSize dateLabelSize = [cell.dateLabel.text sizeWithFont:cell.dateLabel.font];
    CGFloat dateExpansionAmount = fabsf(dateLabelSize.width - cell.dateLabel.frame.size.width) + 10.0f;
    cell.dateLabel.frame = CGRectMake(cell.dateLabel.frame.origin.x - dateExpansionAmount,
                                      cell.dateLabel.frame.origin.y, 
                                      dateLabelSize.width, 
                                      cell.dateLabel.frame.size.height);

    CGFloat nameLabelWidth = cell.dateLabel.frame.origin.x - cell.nameLabel.frame.origin.x;
    cell.nameLabel.frame = CGRectMake(cell.nameLabel.frame.origin.x, 
                                      cell.nameLabel.frame.origin.y, 
                                      nameLabelWidth,
                                      cell.nameLabel.frame.size.height);
}
```

Unfortunately, the results are not correct because I don't think I'm setting/calculating the frame bounds correctly. See the image below.

[image: Image 1] 
[image: Image 2]

Disregarding the problems with the frame calculations is there a better way to approach this problem or is manually positioning the text label frame the only way?

Comment: Did you already try to set the autoResize property on the asked label?

Comment: Do you mean, setting the autoresize properties ie, the struts and springs? - if so yes, that will resize the labels to expand or contract when the device is rotated.

Comment: You correctly set the resizing mask of the date label but not the name label. It should have flexible width and fixed right margin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try use this to set your dateLabel.

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

     static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"NoteCell";

    NoteCell *cell = (NoteCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.dateLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;

    cell.nameLabel.text = @"A name that should be truncated";
    cell.dateLabel.text = @"A long date to use as an example";

    //set frame cell.dateLabel
    CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(INT_MAX, 44); // CGSizeMake(width,height).
    CGSize dateStringSize = [[cell.dateLabel.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:cell.dateLabel.font]
                                                             constrainedToSize:maximumSize 
                                                                 lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    CGRect dateFrame = cell.dateLabel.frame;
    dateFrame.size.width = dateStringSize. width;
    cell.dateLabel.frame = dateFrame;


return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! -- I've tried this method but what happens is the date label gets shifted off the screen past the disclosure indicator.  Basically, since you are increasing the width, instead of widening the label and having it expand to the left it increases the width to the right.

Comment: I've also tried playing around with the struts and springs.  I set the origin anchor to the top right, as opposed to the default top left.  I also have it set so the label autoexpands.  Still no luck as I'm having the same problem as described above.

Answer (score 0):

after you set the text try to call
the method "sizeToFit"
and then you can just get the yourLabel.frame.size.width correctly, so if the 2 labels exceed the cell frame just resize the name label with a lower size and set correct position for the second, starting where the first one ends...

NEW EDIT (see comment)

```
cell.nameLabel.text = @"A name that should be truncated";
cell.dateLabel.text = @"A long date to use as an example";
[cell.nameLabel sizeToFit];
[cell.dateLabel sizeToFit];
// now check if the 2 width exceed cell size:
if (cell.nameLabel.frame.size.width + cell.dateLabel.frame.size.width > cell.frame.size.width){
//resize nameText:
cell.nameLabel.frame.size.width = cell.frame.size.width - cell.dateLabel.frame.size.width;
// ...and maybe consider to give it a minim size requirement
}
// now set the positions
cell.nameLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,cell.nameLabel.frame.size.width,cell.nameLabel.frame.size.height );
cell.dateLabel.frame = CGRectMake(cell.nameLabel.frame.size.width,0,cell.dateLabel.frame.size.width,cell.dateLabel.frame.size.height );
```

ps
be sure your autoresizingMask settings are corrected to top and left correctly for both labels

Comment: I'm giving it a try now but the first thing that i notice is that the `sizeToFit` method resizes and moves the labels out of position which creates it's own set of problems.  Do you think there is a better way to accomplish this goal without manually calculating the widths?

Comment: sizeToFit resize the frame of your uilabel in order to eliminate unused space. this way you can exactly know how large your text is, and now "manually" calculate its width is not so difficult... see NEW EDIT in my answer

Comment: ok I gave it a try and I'm so close to getting it to work - your suggestions are good about sizeToFit.  There is one lingering problem.  The label's origin is fixed and then sizeToFit will expand the label's frame to fit the text however (this is where the problem is) it expands the label to the RIGHT not left, which means it runs off screen past the disclosure indicator.  The label needs to expand the width to the left, not right...

Comment: yes, you're right, that's why you need to use the last two lines of my code (or use other coordinations if needed)