# how to resize text in multi-line or single line when zoom label

Tags: iphone, ios, uilabel

I have been looking for a solution to this, but have not been able to find it. I have a label that I want to automatically resize according to zoom.

Please provide me few line code if you have any idea how to do this.

Thanks

Comment: could you tell me how you do zoom In to label....i struggle on that one...

Answer (score 0):

Since you havent provided any code, I cant guarantee that this will work. However, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439541/how-do-you-dynamically-resize-two-text-label-widths-inside-of-a-uitableviewcell) previous question that deals with the same problem you are having.

Here is some code that resizes labels automatically:

```
cell.dateLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;

cell.nameLabel.text = @"A name that should be truncated";
cell.dateLabel.text = @"A long date to use as an example";
```

Hope this helps!